# Given the graph of $y=f(x)$ on the left, and $f(x)=(x-2)^2-7$ graph the function

Tags: calculus

[image: Given the graph of y=f(x) on the left, and f(x)=(x-2)^2-7 graph the fucntion that woudld represent..]
Given the graph of $y=f(x)$ on the left, and $f(x)=(x-2)^2-7$ graph the fucntion that would represent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Domain represents all $x$ points on the graph. And the range is all $y$ points. So for the $y=f(x)$ case the Domain would be all $x$ while the range would be all $y$ $\ge$ $-7$
And when trying to find the invariant points you can set your function $f(x) = x$ solving for $x$ values gives you your invariant points

Comment: what about the secound question? :(

Comment: no I still don't understand for the 2 question is it all reall numbers x>0 and range x<-7